C# Dataprotector Decrypt function doesn't work with Logon or TokenService
I have code that reads protected values from a config file and decrypts the values into strings. Then the code uses those values in Windows Logon and TokenService functions.
The code works fine when I debug it from my desktop but the values aren't being decrypted correctly when I deploy the code to the server. My desktop is windows 11 and the deployed server runs on windows Server 2016.
If I hard-code the decrypted config values directly into these two functions they work on the deployed server.
When I debug the code that decrypts the config values, the variables are identical to what I hard-coded.
What am I missing?
UPDATE - I found this error in the logs: Decryption failed: The key {a79dd801-99f7-4ca9-a0a2-ad571f9ad08f} was not found in the key ring.
public class EncryptionService : IEncryptionService
{
    private readonly IDataProtector _protector;
    private static readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(EncryptionService));

    // Constructor to initialize the IDataProtector using dependency injection
    public EncryptionService(IDataProtectionProvider provider)
    {
        // unique string that ensures different protection policies for different purposes
        _protector = provider.CreateProtector("MyPurposeIs...");
    }

    // Method to encrypt plain text data
    public string EncryptData(string plainText)
    {
        return _protector.Protect(plainText);
    }

    // Method to decrypt the encrypted data
    public string DecryptData(string encryptedData)
    {
        try
        {
            return _protector.Unprotect(encryptedData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // If decryption fails (e.g., data is tampered or invalid), handle the exception
            return $"Decryption failed: {ex.Message}";
        }
    }

}


public class Utilities : IUtilities
{
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword,
    int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out SafeAccessTokenHandle phToken);
    public IConfiguration _config;

    const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
    const int LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9;

    private static readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Utilities));
    private readonly IEncryptionService _encryptionService;


public Utilities(IConfiguration configuration, IEncryptionService encryptionService)
{
    _config = configuration;
    _encryptionService = encryptionService;
}

//domain, username and password are read from a config file, decrypted, then passed into this function

    public string[]? ImpersonateAndGetFiles(string domain, string username, string password, string sourcePath, string fileSpec)
    {
        string[]? resultArray = null;
        try
        {
            SafeAccessTokenHandle? safeAccessTokenHandle;
        
        

            bool returnValue = LogonUser(username, domain, password,
                                     LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS,
                                     LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                                     out safeAccessTokenHandle);

            if (false == returnValue)
            {

                int ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

                _log.Error($"LogonUser failed with error code : {ret}");
                return resultArray;
            }

            if (safeAccessTokenHandle is not null)
            {
                _log.Info("Logon Successful. Getting file list.");
                #pragma warning disable CA1416 // Validate platform compatibility
                WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(safeAccessTokenHandle, () =>
                {
                    resultArray = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, fileSpec);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                });
                #pragma warning restore CA1416 // Validate platform compatibility
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.Error($"Error: {ex}");
            return resultArray;
        }

        return resultArray;
    }
}

//code that uses the functions
 string? domain = _config["domainCL"];
 string? userName = _config["userNameCL"];
 string? password = _config["passwordCL"];
string? unEncryptedDomain = null;
string? unEncryptedUserName = null;
string? unEncryptedPassword = null;

unEncryptedDomain = _encryptionService.DecryptData(domain);
unEncryptedUserName = _encryptionService.DecryptData(userName);
unEncryptedPassword = _encryptionService.DecryptData(password);
fileList = _utils.ImpersonateAndGetFiles(unEncryptedDomain, unEncryptedUserName, unEncryptedPassword, folder, "*.xml");


Any related logs in the log file or windows event log? (m.b. meaningful message or stacktrace)

The logs indicate error code 206 for the Logon function and the token service returns a message that the client secret is invalid. Like I said, the same code works fine when I run it from my desktop.

I found the problem. There is a key created and stored when files are encrypted. When the application runs on the deployed server, it is running under a different account, which means the key is stored in a different location. I set the key to persist to a common file and then re-encrypted everything with the new key. Then I copied the key file to the folder specified in my program.cs and it works because the code now finds and uses the same key as the one I encrypted the settings with.
  var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
             .ConfigureServices(services => 
             {
                 services.AddSingleton(_config);
                 services.AddTransient<App>();
                 services.AddDataProtection()
                 .SetApplicationName("App")
                 .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\webservices\Keys\") );
                 services.AddTransient<IEncryptionService, EncryptionService>();

             })
             .Build();


Please don't forget to mark your reply as answer to help other guys that having the same issue.
